# Get data from a single row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Usually when I want to iterate over a csv file like this:

```
PRODUCTID|PRODUCTNAME|TYPE|PRODUCTDESCRIPTION
1001|Apple|Fruit|McIntosh apple
1002|Pear|Fruit|Rare name pear
1003|Potato|Root|Common potato
1004|Banana|Fruit|Banana from an island
```

I make this if I want to make a filter:

```
import pandas 
my_products = pandas.read_csv( ... )
fruits = my_products[ my_products.TYPE=="Fruit" ]

for fruit in fruits.itertuples( ):
  doSomething( fruit.PRODUCTNAME, fruit.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION )
```

But if I can filter just one product like this:

```
apple = my_products[ my_products.PRODUCTNAME="Apple" ]
```

How can I get PRODUCTDESCRIPTION without needing to iterate over it as in the previous example?
Because it seems I can't just make something like `doSomething( "Apple", apple.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION )` or `doSomething( "Apple", apple[0].PRODUCTDESCRIPTION )`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly add more info or an example of ur doSomething function, with expected output. SO folks might be able to give u an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply uses `.loc` to specify what you are filtering for, and then add the desired column that you want results for that row for.

```
my_products.loc[my_products['PRODUCTNAME'] == 'Apple']['PRODUCTDESCRIPTION']
```

OR

```
my_products.loc[my_products['PRODUCTNAME'] == 'Apple', 'PRODUCTDESCRIPTION']
```

Output:

```
0    McIntosh apple
Name: PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, dtype: object
```

you can then add `[0]` to the end to access the string. Keep in mind if there are multiple results, you could add `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

```
my_products.loc[my_products['PRODUCTNAME'] == 'Apple']['PRODUCTDESCRIPTION'][0]
```

OR

```
my_products.loc[my_products['PRODUCTNAME'] == 'Apple', 'PRODUCTDESCRIPTION'][0]
```

Ouput:

```
'McIntosh apple'
```

Comment: but that mean I have to tell each column I need as this doesn't behave like a e.g. a dictionary, does it?